# Can the distance between two subsets be reached?

Tags: functional-analysis

Given a metric space $(X,d)$. Let $A$ and $B$ be two nonempty subsets of $X$. If $A$ is compact and $B$ is closed, 
then there exist $x_0\in A$ and $y_0\in B$, such that $d(A,B)=d(x_0,y_0)$?

I know that, if $A$ and $B$ are both compact, then the conclusion is right. But if $B$ is just a closed subset?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Yes, it can. Go read the proof of the statement you know is true and see if compactness of both sets is ever used.

Comment: It is not necessarily true if $B$ is just closed.